# Scala flatten nested map

Tags: scala, scala-collections, dictionary-comprehension

I have a nested Map like this one:

```
Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 3.0, 4 -> 5.0), 6 -> Map(7 -> 8.0))
```

I would like to 'flatten' it in a way such that the keys of the outer and inner maps are paired, i.e. for the example above:

```
Seq((1,2),(1,4),(6,7))
```

what is an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With for-comprehension:

```
val m =  Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 3.0, 4 -> 5.0), 6 -> Map(7 -> 8.0))

scala> for((k1, v1) <- m.toSeq; k2 <- v1.keys) yield (k1, k2)
res4: Seq[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((1,2), (1,4), (6,7))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
val m =  Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 3.0, 4 -> 5.0), 6 -> Map(7 -> 8.0))
m.toSeq.flatMap({case (k, v) => v.keys.map((k,_))})
```